# Delete huge number of nodes in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In my Drupal 7 site, there is a content type with 13,000 existing nodes (contents). To Delete all nodes, I've tried '[views bulk operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)' module to delete 500 nodes at a time but its showing "Request Timed out". I am able to delete only 50 nodes at a time through admin successfully, if more than 50 it shows "request times out".

Can some one help me on this so that i can delete huge number of nodes at a time.

Thanks,
Chaithanya

Comment: Please don't [cross-post questions](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76268/delete-huge-number-of-nodes-in-drupal). Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a module for that (TM).

See [Bulk Delete](http://drupal.org/project/bulkdelete).

That will use the Batch API to delete the nodes to avoid timeout or memory issues when deleting thousands of nodes with a single call to node_delete_multiple().

Bulk Delete is an abandoned module.  See for alternatives:

- [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)
- [Delete All](http://drupal.org/project/delete_all)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = db_query("SELECT n.nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = '####'");
while ($n = db_fetch_object($query)) {
    node_delete($n->nid);
}
```

Using the above query to delete the node.

Comment: Wouldn't that timeout horribly.. ie, not fix the problem. If you'd suggested running something similar via drush, then yeah, I can see that working via CLI.

Answer (score 0):

might want to increase PHP execution time in php.ini configuration file.